# installing ffi gem manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install the ffi gem. it is a dependency for one of my apps. I have been trying for hours to get this to work. I am receiving this error:

```
#error "Use of <stdbool.h> is valid only in a c99 compilation environment."
```

I know the solution to this error is to add `CFLAGS= -std=c99`. 
the problem is that when I run

`gem install ffi -v '1.3.1' -- --with-cflags=-std=c99`

I am still receiving the error the make and in the log I see that it is not recognizing the `CFLAGS` I have added.

I then decided to go into the `makefile` and manually add the `CFLAGS` then run `make` and `make install`

this seemed to work I received no errors but when I `bundle install` in my app it still does not recognize the ffi gem to be installed and recreates the `makefile` without the CFLAGS and fails again.

is there something I am missing when doing this manually??

or is there a way to force the CFLAGS from gem install??

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here but try this:

```
CFLAGS="-std=c99" gem install ffi -v '1.3.1'
```

Comment: no luck with this ended up with the same error :( thanks though...seems to be the only way it recognizes CFLAGS is when I edit the makefile